# PIVOT SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

**SQL Server 2008 R2**

**PIVOT IO Stats**

I have a script that collects IO stats from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats once a day and stocks them in a table.  I want to be able to use these stats to generate graphs.

Using PIVOT I have created columns based on the dates the stats were collected

```
select 'read io stall',[2012-10-17], [2012-10-18], [2012-10-19], [2012-10-20], [2012-10-21]
from ( 
    select io_stall_read_ms, date_snap
    from dbo.tbl_io_stats
    where database_name = 'mydb'
    ) up
PIVOT (max(io_stall_read_ms) FOR date_snap IN ([2012-10-17], [2012-10-18], [2012-10-19], [2012-10-20], [2012-10-21]))
AS pvt
UNION
select 'write io stall', [2012-10-17], [2012-10-18], [2012-10-19], [2012-10-20], [2012-10-21]
from ( 
    select database_name, io_stall_write_ms, date_snap
    from dbo.tbl_io_stats
    where database_name = 'mydb'
    ) up
PIVOT (max(io_stall_write_ms) FOR date_snap IN ([2012-10-17], [2012-10-18], [2012-10-19], [2012-10-20], [2012-10-21]))
AS pvt
```

**Resulting table:**

```
Type Stat   2012-10-17  2012-10-18  2012-10-19  2012-10-20  2012-10-21
read io stall   34449971    34499918    34504701    40383037    40852412
write io stall  20948385    20996323    21001665    24130053    24193110
```

As is, I have to add each new date as an additional column.

**Question:**

Is it possible to generate the PIVOT column list automatically or is there another way to do what I'm thinking of?

Instead of

```
FOR date_snap IN ([2012-10-17], [2012-10-18], [2012-10-19], [2012-10-20], [2012-10-21]
```

Something like:

```
FOR date_snap IN (SELECT DISTINCT date_snap FROM tbl_io_stats)
```

**Update with RichardTheKiwi's answer**

Here is the new working query, thank you RichardTheKiwi

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ios.date_snap) 
            FROM tbl_io_stats ios
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT database_name + '' read io stall'', ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select database_name, io_stall_read_ms, date_snap
                from dbo.tbl_io_stats
                where database_name = ''mydb''
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(io_stall_read_ms)
                for date_snap in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            union
SELECT database_name + '' write io stall'', ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select database_name, io_stall_write_ms, date_snap
                from dbo.tbl_io_stats
                where database_name = ''mydb''
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(io_stall_write_ms)
                for date_snap in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

--print @query
execute(@query)
```

Comment: Would it be easier to have a table with three columns; Type Stat, Date, and Value; and then pivot when you're reporting on the data?  You can't index based on columns so I'm not sure how performance is going to be after you get a decent number of columns there.  And if you're going to start doing averages, maxes, or any other aggregation you'll have to un-pivot it to get them as different rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has that feature (pivot columns from subquery) but not SQL Server.  The best you can do is dynamic SQL to generate the PIVOT statement, e.g. [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404455/573261).

Comment: Could you direct me to a PostgreSQL example?  I know there is `crosstab(text,text)`, which claims to do that, but it does not...

Comment: You're right. I was 100% certain Oracle has it, but wasn't sure about PostgreSQL so I said "probably", which has now been removed.

Comment: My question was a genuine one for I'd be more than happy to find the solution :)

Comment: In answer to your question, yes Excel will do this for you.  Try the Data tab.  You can link directly to a table, then chart your data.  Plus, my point is valid; for this example you are wasting your time pivoting in SQL Server.  Whilst a kludgy dynamic SQL solution is possible, this kind of data can be charted _easily_ without being pivoted by either Excel or SSRS matrix control.  Try it!

Comment: You're talking about a "generating graphs".  And I'm suggesting Excel can do that, easily, straight from your data.  SSRS matrix can also deal with this unpivoted.

Comment: Just for _fun_ I put the two forms of data into Excel and charted each one.  Guess what happened?